# Your current directory is stenton. Display detailed information about the markham directory itself, not the files within it:

Tags: linux, unix

sample_dir2

`-- sample_dir

```
|-- admin
|-- cambridge
|   `-- security
|       |-- annex
|       `-- parking
|-- history.exe
|-- markham
|   |-- annex
|   |-- building1
|   `-- parking
`-- stenton
    |-- gen_ed
    `-- lib_arts
        `-- english.txt
```

the ~ isnt sample_dir2 but the dir that which sample_dir is inside

Comment: try `stat ../markham`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -ld ../markham`
Is that what you want? If not, please edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: nope that also didnt work thanks for trying

Comment: @Antonioperinchief suggested an edit of my original `ls -d markham` to `ls -ld ../markham`, and the suggestion was rejected even though it is 100% correct. So I am implementing the suggestion myself.  Antonio, please don't be discouraged by the sometimes rude and/or inexplicable behaviour you sometimes encounter on the site. Keep making a positive contribution.